# Как сделать так чтобы при выборе RadioButton появлялись новые Элементы?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Как сделать так чтобы при выборе RadioButton появлялись новые Элементы?

Нажимаю на RadioButton - red.

Ниже должно появиться `<label for="Name">Name</label>`

```
@Html.RadioButton("color", "red")
<span>красный</span> <br />
@Html.RadioButton("color", "blue")
<span>синий</span> <br />
@Html.RadioButton("color", "green", true)
<span>зеленый</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddlefcn/tk94x8xu/

html:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red"> красный<br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue"> синий<br>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="green"> зеленый
</form>

<label id="Name">Name</label>
```

javascript:

```
$('input:radio[name="color"]').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $("#Name").html( $(this).val() );
        }
    });
```

Обрати внимание, использую последний [JQuery framework](https://jquery.com/).